# Convenções de quando utilizar _ ou $ em identificadores de Java?

Tags: java, estilo-de-codificação

Quando utilizar _ ou $ nos identificadores? Isto é, em quais casos devo utilizar _ ou $ para deixar o meu código mais organizado. Por exemplo, devo usar $ na frente de nomes de variáveis quando estiver construindo um *framework*?

Answer (score 3):

De uma maneira geral nunca pelo menos um deles.

`$` é considerado de uso interno e só o compilador deveria gerar identificadores com este caractere. Claro que exceções sempre podem ser feitas se tiver um bom motivo. Alguma ferramenta que gere código talvez possa se valer disso para garantir que os identificadores criados por ela não conflitam com o que o programador usar. Mais um motivo para o programador não usá-lo em código normal. É muito raro quem precise disto.

Se usar essa convenção em um *framework* provavelmente está fazendo algo errado. Mas sem um caso concreto é difícil afirmar.

`_` não tem uso específico e pode ser usando quando achar que deve. Porém a recomendação é não usar. É uma questão de estilo, Java evita seu uso. Se quer identificar que é uma palavra nova apenas use maiúsculo (camelCase). Usa-se exceção quando o identificador é uma constante. Como Java adota a convenção antiga de constante serem ALL_CAPS o *underscore* acaba sendo necessário para separar palavras.

Há quem goste de usar o *underscore* no início do nome em algumas situações, como em variáveis privadas. Não vejo necessidade ou ganho.

O importante é adotar um padrão e segui-lo sempre.